# On scroll animate menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I m trying to create in jquery top menu, with height depending on window scroll position. When I use $(selector).css("height", "value"); everything is ok but when I try do this by animate it does not work correct. Here is my code. Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE   html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
</style>
<body>
    <nav style="background-color:red; height:100px;" class="navbar-fixed-top navbar navbar-default my-navbar">
    </nav>
    <div style="width:100%; height:2000px; background-color:blue;" class="content"> 
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var top=$(window).scrollTop();
                if(top>10){
                    $(".my-navbar").animate({height: '50px'}, "slow");
                }else{
                    $(".my-navbar").animate({height: '100px'}, "slow");
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First Solution:**

use `stop()` for `animation`:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var top=$(window).scrollTop();
if(top > 10){
$(".my-navbar").stop().animate({height: '50px'}, "slow");
}else{
$(".my-navbar").stop().animate({height: '100px'}, "slow");
}
})
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akbudycr/)**

---

**Second Solution:**

Use `addClass` and `removeClass`:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var top=$(window).scrollTop();
if(top > 10){
$(".my-navbar").addClass('NavBar2');
}else{
$(".my-navbar").removeClass('NavBar2');
}
})
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akbudycr/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not exactly its not working, its just "its not working as expected", since if you leave it for a while it does its job. The problem is that previous animation is still running when you try to animate it again. You might need to stop the previous animation first by calling jquery method stop()

```
if(top>10){
    $(".my-navbar").stop().animate({height: '50px'}, "slow");
}else{
    $(".my-navbar").stop().animate({height: '100px'}, "slow");
}
```

Hope it helps